# Need a simple way to set width and height of an empty block element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <style type="text/css" media="all">
         .prod
        {
         display: inline-block;
         border: 1px solid grey;
         width: 158;
         height: 124;
         cursor: pointer;
        }
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function swap(x,y,z)
         {
          var node = document.getElementById(x);
          node.src = node.src.indexOf(y)>=0 ? z : y;
          node.style.border = node.src.indexOf(y)>=0 ? '' : '1px solid grey';
          node.style.position = node.src.indexOf(y)>=0 ? 'static':'fixed';
          node.style.top = node.src.indexOf(y)>=0 ? '' : '20%';
          node.style.left = node.src.indexOf(y)>=0 ? '' : '20%';
         }
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span class="prod">   
          <img id="im0001" src="thumbnail.gif" onclick="swap ('im0001','thumbnail.gif','fullsize.gif');" /> 
      </span>
      <br />
      <br />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: add pixels to your dimensions (ie 159px).

Comment: This script work well, but i need to make the span container have width and height set.

Comment: @user701709: I was talking about missing dimensions in your CSS definition. Not script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in one of the comments, your height and width are incorrect. 
You need to change width: 158 to: width: 158px

Same goes with height

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jwKpN/

Comment: I don't know why I first started writing a comment instead of an answer. ;)

Comment: I can see now, what a childish mistake I have made. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

### Missing CSS dimension units

You have to set dimension unit in your CSS for it to work. Your CSS only defines width as

```
width: 158;
```

that should be:

```
width: 158px;
```

That would do the trick for you.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/au555/).

Comment: I can see now, what a childish mistake I have made.